# .NetCore Pipeline - Resource filter being called twice per request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I create a resource filter to log the body of post request on .net core 2.2, but I'm facing a very strange problem, because it is being called twice, on every request.

I looked over the fiddler to be certain of a single request has been sent to the server.

The following is the code of the filter and the registry on Mvc pipeline, and the configure method on startup.

Filter Registry:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(options.Filters.Add(typeof(ApiPostLogFilter)));
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

Resource Filter Code:

```
 public class ApiPostLogFilter : IAsyncResourceFilter
    {
        ApiRequestLogService _apiRequestLogService;

        public ApiPostLogFilter(ApiRequestLogService ApiRequestLogService)
        {
            _apiRequestLogService = ApiRequestLogService;
        }

        public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            await ApiPostRequestLogHelper.LogPostRequest(context.HttpContext, _apiRequestLogService);
            await next.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Configure Method:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
            }

            //Config para que não haja timeout no Redis.
            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 1000);        

            app.UseEndpointRouting();
            app.UseMiddleware<TenantIdentifierStartupMiddleware>();
            app.UseMiddleware<MiniProfilerMiddleware>();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Comment: What's inside `ApiPostRequestLogHelper.LogPostRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you adding the filter twice..

change :

```
options.Filters.Add(options.Filters.Add(typeof(ApiPostLogFilter)));
```

to :

```
options.Filters.Add(typeof(ApiPostLogFilter));
```

Comment: I am currently using in this formt services.AddControllers(ot => ot.Filters.Add(typeof(ApiExceptionAttribute))); , but still its hitting twice upon error. i placed the attribute "[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]" in the Filter class but still same result

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was adding the Filter twice as below in `Startup.cs`
[image]

Check if its same in your case as well.